# Another mystery to solve.....plant identification

Tags: identification

I got this plant at a nursery sale with no tag in it.  Have been watching it for three years now ~ there does not appear to be a flower on it OR I've just missed it's bloom time. This year I noticed, despite the very rigid vertical main "stem", there are a few off-shoots from the bottom of the plant that seem to want to crawl or vine.  It has been quite slow growing (not withstanding, the new vining branches seem to have grown overnight.) standing only about 2 1/2 feet tall. The leaves are quite small ~ maybe an inch long or so. Not shiny. And in the fall there are tight little red berries all along the branches.

Here are some pictures.....
Thank you kindly, Karen

[image]
[image]

[image]
[image]

Comment: More information, please. What zone are you in or where are you (be fairly specific)? Do the leaves change colour in the fall or just drop off? It obviously has flowers or it couldn't produce berries.

Comment: Sorry!  Zone 5 Nova Scotia.  I think the leaves just fall off, but please leave that out of the equation, because it is just a guess.  I cannot remember for sure.

Answer (score 3):

Looks to me like a pink version (and yes I know there are some) of the common snowberry (*Symphoricarpos alba*).  I know all the species, and most that I found seemed more brite pink than the deep pink in your picture.  One of the features of snowberry is they last well into the winter (at least here in the Pacific Northwest). Just from clicking on a couple of species from Wikipedia, I might hazard a guess that you have *Symphoricarpos × chenaultii*.

**Update**

@nic I "opposite decussate", and would have to disagree about *S. alba* (see photos below).  Then again, I was never claiming that was the correct species. :)  I'm perfectly happy to be wrong, but will provide some photos of flowers, leaves on *S. alba* with the hopes that it helps the O.P. in identifying.
[image: close-up of flower]
[image: Close-up of leaf structure]

Comment: I've looked at several sites that discuss the Symphoricarpos x chenaultii ~ some aspects of their description seem right.  But I remember the berries looking a bit gnarled; not smooth or jewel-like.  I will keep my eye on it as the weeks pass to see what flower is produced.  I'll take pictures and come back to confirm or re-state the question.  Thank you so much; I don't know how you guys are able to sleuth these things out.  Well done!  Thank you, Karen

Comment: Symphoricarpos alba has an opposite leaf arrangement, but these photos have opposite decussate arrangement so it's unlikely.

Comment: What about those red fluffy things in the first picture?  What are they? Symphoricarpos...looks good, I guess I am thrown by the scale.

Comment: Ben, are these your hands?  Most definitely those of a gardener.  Maybe we should all share pictures of our hands!

Comment: Yep my hands I'd just taken a break from weeding gravel steps. Check my bio out if you haven't. I like the idea of a hands thread. Is it on the parameters of the site¿

Answer (score 1):

Leaves look like a *Lonicera*, known as honeysuckle. Hard to confirm without a picture of the flowers.
Colour and shape of berries suggests it is *Lonicera xylosteum*.

Comment: I have a couple of honeysuckle on the property.  I've never seen this berry on them.  And they grew so fast.  This on has stayed like a little minature tree for three years.

Answer (score 1):

I will throw my ID in until we get more information.  Looks like honeysuckle to me.  I am going with Tatarian Honeysuckle...Lonicera tatarica [Lonicera tatarica](https://safe.search.tools/images?dkt=TG9uaWNlcmE,&o=100)

Comment: Its definitely a honeysuckle of some type- looks a bit dry to me because of the amount of mould on the leaves perhaps by having it planted within a rain shadow of a house- not much can be done, just mulch around the plant and water a lot- other than that, I personally would remove it for something that likes those conditions.